# Orientation bundle and its flat connection

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, orientation

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold (which is not assumed to be orientable), and write $o(TM)\to M$ for its orientation bundle. Equivalently, it is the top exterior bundle $\Lambda^n(TM)\to M$. In any case, it is a real line bundle and is flat, where the locally constant transition functions are given by the sign of the Jacobian matrix of the transition functions of $TM\to M$. Let $\nabla^{o(TM)}$ be the corresponding flat connection.

My questions are:

1. Is the flat connection on $o(TM)\to M$ unique (in some/any sense)? I saw in somewhere  the following sentence "Let $\nabla^{o(TM)}$ be the natural flat connection on $o(TM)\to M$". I don't understand what natural means there.
2. Is the flat connection $\nabla^{o(TM)}$ induced by some other connection? Let say I put a Riemannian metric on $M$, and denote by $\nabla^{TM}$ its Levi-Civita connection. What is the difference $\nabla^{o(TM)}-\nabla^{\Lambda^n(TM)}$?

Any reference related to the orientation bundle and its flat connection will be appreciated.

Comment: In the orientable case trivialize the bundle by choosing a volume form. 
At this point there is a canonical flat connection. 
Different choices of trivializations will lead to different flat connections all different by a gauge transformation. 
In the non-orientable case pass to the orientable double cover.

Comment: @Overflowian Thanks. This is great~